# How to split a string in multiple ones (Php)?

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I want to split a big number/string for example `123456789123456789` into 6 smaller strings/numbers of 3 characters each. So the result would be `123` `456` `789` `123` `456` `789`. How can I do this?

Comment: I meant 6 variables, not just separate them. For example $small[0] = 123, $small[1] = 456 and so on..

Comment: You could try this with `$small = explode(' ', chunk_split($yourString, 3, ' '));` where `$yourString` is your number

Answer (score 4):

Use [chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php):

```
$var = "123456789123456789";
$split_string = chunk_split($var, 3); // 3 is the length of each chunk
```

If you want your result as an array, you can use [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
$var = "123456789123456789";
$array = str_split($var, 3); // 3 is the length of each chunk
```

Comment: For number "12345" the result will be "123" "45", but I think that he want get "12" "345"

Comment: To achieve that, you can do use strrev: `$result = strrev(chunk_split (strrev($var), 3, ' ')));

Comment: @AntonTodua - `but I think that he want get "12" "345"` - Where did he say this? If true, a regex for that would be `\d{1,3}(?=\d{3})|\d{1,3}`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$string = '123456789123456789';
preg_match_all('/(\d{3})/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 456
    [2] => 789
    [3] => 123
    [4] => 456
    [5] => 789
)
```

`\d` is a number and `{3}` is 3 of the previously found character (in this case a number.

....

or if there won't always be even groupings:

```
$string = '12345678912345678922';
preg_match_all('/(\d{1,3})/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 456
    [2] => 789
    [3] => 123
    [4] => 456
    [5] => 789
    [6] => 22
)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rX0pJ1/1

Comment: what happens if the string is not divisible by 3?

Comment: It's wrong for number which contain not 3*n digit. For example "12345".

Comment: Update posted for non-even 3's. Down-vote and upvote retraction on update, why?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `chunk_split()` function.
It splits a string into smaller

```
$string = "123456789123456789";
echo chunk_split ($string, 3, " ");
```

will output

```
123 456 789 123 456 789
```

First parameter is the string to be chunked. The second is the chunk length and the third is what you want at the end of each chunk.

See [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) for further information